# How to define "or" logically

Tags: programming-logic

Recently, I came across a problem that required me to define the logical "OR" operator programmatically, but without using the operator itself.

What I came up with is this:

```cs
OR(arg1, arg2)
  if arg1 = True and arg2 = True
     return True

  else if arg1 = True and arg2 = False
     return True

  else if arg1 = False and arg2 = True
     return True

  else:
     return False
```

Is this logic correct, or did I miss something?

Comment: Only that I looked up "how to define 'or' logically" for about half an hour and didn't find anything, so if its in wikipedia, thanks for the link :D

Comment: @gnat:  To be fair, a truth table lists the outputs for each combination of the inputs and the Wikipedia article gives a description of the function.  I think what the OP is really asking is how to define a logical OR _programmatically_ without the use of the operator itself.

Comment: @Blrfl I can't read asker's mind, I can only see what is written in the question: "Is this logic correct?"

Comment: @user3687688 Can you please clarify the primitives we are allowed to use?

Comment: If you are interested in this kind of stuff, I think you’ll love this book: http://nand2tetris.org/

Comment: Nitpicking: There's another problem with your solution.  Popular languages use short-circuit evaluation for `or`. That means that if `arg1` is true, `arg2` is not evaluated.  This comes in to play when you have something like `or(foo(), bar())`. If foo() returns true, bar() is not even called because its result isn't necessary. The problem is that usually all function arguments are evaluated when a function is called, so `arg1` and `arg2` are evaluated regardless of how you implement `Or`. In c++ you can use a macro. In C# you could use an Action as an argument. Or you could use classes.

Comment: this question has started a collective spasm of micro-optimization ;)

Comment: @RobY at [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), a question like this would likely be voted down for being boring and quickly closed as lacking "objective primary winning criterion". But Programmers regulars seem to simply lack experience of handling code-golfey topics (not that I complain, I like it that code-golf stuff rarely leaks in here, especially since there is a dedicated site for those willing to really enjoy stuff like that)

Comment: You could use the ternary operator `return arg1 ? arg1 : arg2;`

Comment: I have got to know why you needed to re-define the `or` operator.

Comment: @Kyle Strand It was to make an or function for a strange pseudo 4th gen language in some code for work, and I got curious to see what the logic would be if I could't use the or operator.

Comment: @Matthew I doubt his language has `?:` if it doesn't even have `or` :)

Comment: I am surprised no one asked if this was homework... I thought it was when I saw the title on the hot topics list.

Comment: True and False are usually represented as 1 and 0, with this you can compute the boolean functions with integer operations.  `OR(a,b) = a+b-a*b`, `AND(a,b) = a*b`, `NOT(a) = 1-a`

Comment: Is it against the rules to use bitwise or?

Comment: If not, then assuming that `arg1` and `arg2` are boolean expressions, and convertible to integral types such as `int`, wouldn't returning the bitwise OR  of the two expressions effectively have the same effect as logical OR?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I'd say that's correct, but could you not condense it down to something such as this?

```
or(arg1, arg2)
    if arg1 == true
        return true
    if arg2 == true
        return true

    return false
```

Since you're doing an or comparison, I don't think you really need to check the combination. It just matters if one of them is true to return true. Otherwise we want to return false.

If you're looking for a shorter version that is less verbose, this will also work:

```
or(arg1, arg2)
    if arg1
        return arg1
    return arg2
```

Comment: You could also remove the "else" on line 4 (leaving just `if arg2 == true`).

Comment: @DawsonToth There's many different ways you can spin it, depends if you want to be verbose or condensed really. I'd be happy with the else if but it sounds like this is a pseudo code question so I'd probably leave it like this for clarity. Very true though!

Comment: @BlueHat It seems slightly inconsistent to use an else if, but not an else at the end.

Comment: @SBoss that is a fair point, I did this mostly out of habit as a some langauges complain with warnings when you don't have a return at the root of the method. However as  this is a pseudo question you're probably right about clarity. I'll remove the else from line 4 as suggested.

Comment: I simplified it down for you. (I also changed `true` to `arg1` to make it work better with non-Boolean types.)

Comment: @Mehrdad Thanks! I've included the old answer back just because I feel it's a bit more verbose and explains the solution a tiny bit clearer. But your solution is much smaller and does the same job.

Comment: even better (worse): `or(a, b): a ? a : b`

Comment: @kai My only gripe with that would be that this isn't a language specific question and not all languages support that short hand format. However it's totally valid in most languages and would work just as well.

Answer (score 148):

Here is a solution without or, and, not, comparisons and boolean literals:

```
or(arg1, arg2)
  if arg1
    return arg1
  else
    return arg2
```

It probably doesn't get much more fundamental than that ;)

Comment: Darn, I somehow didn't see this when scanning the existing answers to see if my answer was covered. A well, have a +1.

Comment: +1 for a slightly shorter answer than mine. However I'd be tempted to drop the "else" as well just for elegance.

Comment: @BlueHat But then the two returns would be indented differently ;)

Comment: I would like to get an EUR each time someone compares something against `true` or `false`.

Comment: @JensG Well, where do you think Bill Gates' income comes from?

Comment: @JensG Agreed in general, but I have stumbled upon one good use case of comparing against `false`, namely `if (someCollection.add(someElement) == false)`, which means "if adding the element did not work", and it reads a lot more natural to me than negating via `!`.

Comment: JavaScript `||` operator in a nutshell (when implemented in a dynamically typed language).

Comment: @FredOverflow I've never been a fan of the `if(!x)`, I find it very easy to skip over and miss when reading code. I think being verbose with == false makes a lot more sense. Where possible always comparing to true tends to read better in my books.

Comment: I disagree that skipping the else is more elegant. I would also elide else when the conditions are asymmetric, i.e. the if part handles exceptional situation. But when the if part and else part are symmetric, as in here, I would spell out the else.

Comment: `return arg1 if arg1 else arg2`?

Comment: @octatoan Sure, if his language supports that... which I doubt.

Comment: The language of this answer looked like Python to me.

Answer (score 107):

One line of code:

```
return not (not arg1 and not arg2)
```

No branching, no OR.

In a C-based language, it would be:

```
return !(!arg1 && !arg2);
```

This is simply an application of [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): `(A || B) == !(!A && !B)`

Comment: I think this approach is the best solution since (in my opinion) an `if/else` construct is the same as using OR, just with a different name.

Comment: @Nick using `if` is equivalent to equality. Normally in machine code an `if` is implemented as arithmetic followed by a comparison to zero with a jump.

Comment: For reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: I like this approach because it short-circuits IFF `and` short circuits, thus providing consistency among the operators.

Comment: @Mephy in the future you can edit an answer to add details such this. At your rep level the edit will need to be reviewed, but it is an encouraged way to contribute to the site. This time I added it myself.

Comment: @Snowman That's true. I meant that `if (a) return true; else if (b) return true;` seems more or less morally equivalent to `if (a OR b) return true;`, but that view may well be open to dispute.

Comment: The catch with this approach is that it breaks the convention in many languages that, eg, `0 or 'abc'` should give `'abc'`, not `true`

Comment: @sapi True, but I prefer to work with languages with sane boolean operators (aka "the actual boolean operators")

Comment: Well done! Kudos for using De Morgan's Law, and getting to the heart of boolean algebra! You can create __any__ boolean expression with suitable combinations of `NOT` and either `AND` or `OR` -- or either one of the composite `NAND` (`NOT AND`) or `NOR` (`NOT OR`) functions.

Comment: @KyleStrand, While this solution is short-circuiting, so will the implementations in other answers using `if`. Further, the short-circuiting isn't especially relevant, since both arguments have been evaluated _anyway_ as they're being passed to the "or" function.

Comment: @BrianS Sure, though I was thinking of this more in terms of replacing `or` statements with `and` statements than as a function (despite the framing of the question).

Answer (score 13):

If you only have `and` and `not`, you can use DeMorgan's law to flip around `and`:

```
if not (arg1 = False and arg2 = False)
  return True
else
  return False
```

... or (even more simply)

```
if arg1 = False and arg2 = False
  return false
else
  return true
```

...

And since we've all apparently become fixated on optimizing something that is almost always available as a machine instruction anyway, that boils down to:

```
return not(not arg1 and not arg2)

return arg1 ? true : arg2
```

etc. etc. etc. etc.

Since most languages provide a conditional-and, odds are the "and" operator implies a branch anyway.

...

If all you have is `nand` (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic)):

return nand(nand(arg1, arg1), nand(arg2, arg2))

Comment: Simplify: `return not (not arg1 and not arg2)`

Comment: @Snowman you should really make that an answer so I could upvote it.  You are (currently) the only one here who didn't go with branching.

Comment: my nand solution doesn't branch ;)

Comment: Was going to add the NAND solution, but you beat me to it. Everything should be implemented in terms of NAND.

Comment: @Andy: Actually, everything should be defined in terms of NOR. ;-)

Comment: Good work with the pure `nand` solution.

Answer (score 13):

## Functions (ECMAScript)

All you need are function definitions and function calls. You don't need any branching, conditionals, operators or builtin functions. I will demonstrate an implementation using ECMAScript.

First, let's define two functions called `true` and `false`. We could define them any way we want, they are completely arbitrary, but we will define them in a very special way which has some advantages as we will see later:

```js
const tru = (thn, _  ) => thn,
      fls = (_  , els) => els;
```

`tru` is a function with two parameters which simply ignores its second argument and returns the first. `fls` is also a function with two parameters which simply ignores its first argument and returns the second.

Why did we encode `tru` and `fls` this way? Well, this way, the two functions not only represent the two concepts of `true` and `false`, no, at the same time, they also represent the concept of "choice", in other words, they are also an `if`/`then`/`else` expression! We evaluate the `if` condition and pass it the `then` block and the `else` block as arguments. If the condition evaluates to `tru`, it will return the `then` block, if it evaluates to `fls`, it will return the `else` block. Here's an example:

```js
tru(23, 42);
// => 23
```

This returns `23`, and this:

```js
fls(23, 42);
// => 42
```

returns `42`, just as you would expect.

There is a wrinkle, however:

```js
tru(console.log("then branch"), console.log("else branch"));
// then branch
// else branch
```

This prints *both* `then branch` and `else branch`! Why?

Well, it *returns* the return value of the first argument, but it *evaluates* both arguments, since ECMAScript is strict and always evaluates all arguments to a function before calling the function. IOW: it evaluates the first argument which is `console.log("then branch")`, which simply returns `undefined` and has the side-effect of printing `then branch` to the console, *and* it evaluates the second argument, which also returns `undefined` and prints to the console as a side-effect. Then, it returns the first `undefined`.

In λ-calculus, where this encoding was invented, that's not a problem: λ-calculus is *pure*, which means it doesn't have any side-effects; therefore you would never notice that the second argument also gets evaluated. Plus, λ-calculus is *lazy* (or at least, it is often evaluated under normal order), meaning, it doesn't actually evaluate arguments which aren't needed. So, IOW: in λ-calculus the second argument would never be evaluated, and if it were, we wouldn't notice.

ECMAScript, however, is *strict*, i.e. it always evaluates all arguments. Well, actually, not always: the `if`/`then`/`else`, for example, only evaluates the `then` branch if the condition is `true` and only evaluates the `else` branch if the condition is `false`. And we want to replicate this behavior with our `iff`. Thankfully, even though ECMAScript isn't lazy, it has a way to delay the evaluation of a piece of code, the same way almost every other language does: wrap it in a function, and if you never call that function, the code will never get executed.

So, we wrap both blocks in a function, and at the end call the function that is returned:

```js
tru(() => console.log("then branch"), () => console.log("else branch"))();
// then branch
```

prints `then branch` and

```js
fls(() => console.log("then branch"), () => console.log("else branch"))();
// else branch
```

prints `else branch`.

We could implement the traditional `if`/`then`/`else` this way:

```js
const iff = (cnd, thn, els) => cnd(thn, els);

iff(tru, 23, 42);
// => 23

iff(fls, 23, 42);
// => 42
```

Again, we need some extra function wrapping when calling the `iff` function and the extra function call parentheses in the definition of `iff`, for the same reason as above:

```js
const iff = (cnd, thn, els) => cnd(thn, els)();

iff(tru, () => console.log("then branch"), () => console.log("else branch"));
// then branch

iff(fls, () => console.log("then branch"), () => console.log("else branch"));
// else branch
```

Now that we have those two definitions, we can implement `or`. First, we look at the truth table for `or`: if the first operand is truthy, then the result of the expression is the same as the first operand. Otherwise, the result of the expression is the result of the second operand. In short: if the first operand is `true`, we return the first operand, otherwise we return the second operand:

```js
const orr = (a, b) => iff(a, () => a, () => b);
```

Let's check out that it works:

```js
orr(tru,tru);
// => tru(thn, _) {}

orr(tru,fls);
// => tru(thn, _) {}

orr(fls,tru);
// => tru(thn, _) {}

orr(fls,fls);
// => fls(_, els) {}
```

Great! However, that definition looks a little ugly. Remember, `tru` and `fls` already act like a conditional all by themselves, so really there is no need for `iff`, and thus all of that function wrapping at all:

```
const orr = (a, b) => a(a, b);
```

There you have it: `or` (plus other boolean operators) defined with nothing but function definitions and function calls in just a handful of lines:

```js
const tru = (thn, _  ) => thn,
      fls = (_  , els) => els,
      orr = (a  , b  ) => a(a, b),
      nnd = (a  , b  ) => a(b, a),
      ntt = a          => a(fls, tru),
      xor = (a  , b  ) => a(ntt(b), b),
      iff = (cnd, thn, els) => cnd(thn, els)();
```

Unfortunately, this implementation is rather useless: there are no functions or operators in ECMAScript which return `tru` or `fls`, they all return `true` or `false`, so we can't use them with our functions. But there's still a lot we can do. For example, this is an implementation of a singly-linked list:

```js
const cons = (hd, tl) => which => which(hd, tl),
      car  = l => l(tru),
      cdr  = l => l(fls);
```

---

## Objects (Scala)

You may have noticed something peculiar: `tru` and `fls` play a double role, they act both as the data values `true` and `false`, but at the same time, they also act as a conditional expression. They are *data* and *behavior*, bundled up into one … uhm … "thing" … or (dare I say) *object*!

Indeed, `tru` and `fls` are objects. And, if you have ever used Smalltalk, Self, Newspeak or other object-oriented languages, you will have noticed that they implement booleans in exactly the same way. I will demonstrate such an implementation here in Scala:

```scala
sealed abstract trait Buul {
  def apply[T, U <: T, V <: T](thn: ⇒ U)(els: ⇒ V): T
  def &&&(other: ⇒ Buul): Buul
  def |||(other: ⇒ Buul): Buul
  def ntt: Buul
}

case object Tru extends Buul {
  override def apply[T, U <: T, V <: T](thn: ⇒ U)(els: ⇒ V): U = thn
  override def &&&(other: ⇒ Buul) = other
  override def |||(other: ⇒ Buul): this.type = this
  override def ntt = Fls
}

case object Fls extends Buul {
  override def apply[T, U <: T, V <: T](thn: ⇒ U)(els: ⇒ V): V = els
  override def &&&(other: ⇒ Buul): this.type = this
  override def |||(other: ⇒ Buul) = other
  override def ntt = Tru
}

object BuulExtension {
  import scala.language.implicitConversions
  implicit def boolean2Buul(b: ⇒ Boolean) = if (b) Tru else Fls
}

import BuulExtension._

(2 < 3) { println("2 is less than 3") } { println("2 is greater than 3") }
// 2 is less than 3
```

This BTW is why the Replace Conditional With Polymorphism Refactoring always works: you can always replace any and every conditional in your program with polymorphic message dispatch, because as we have just shown, polymorphic message dispatch can replace conditionals by simply implementing them. Languages like Smalltalk, Self and Newspeak are existence proof of that, because those languages don't even have conditionals. (They also don't have loops, BTW, or really *any* sort of language built-in control structures except for polymorphic message dispatch aka virtual method calls.)

---

## Pattern Matching (Haskell)

You could also define `or` using pattern matching, or something like Haskell's partial function definitions:

```haskell
True ||| _ = True
_    ||| b = b
```

Of course, pattern matching is a form of conditional execution, but then again, so is object-oriented message dispatch.

Comment: How about `False ||| False = False` and `_ ||| _ = True` instead? :)

Comment: @FredOverflow: That would require always evaluating the right operand. Usually Boolean operators are expected to be non-strict in their right argument aka "short-circuiting".

Comment: Ah, of course. I knew there had to be a deeper reason :)

Comment: The first part reminded me immediately of Eric Lippert's great series about [continuation passing style](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/21/continuation-passing-style-revisited-part-one.aspx). Purely coincidental but still fun :)

Comment: @JörgWMittag FredOverflow's definition is appropriately short-circuiting. Try `True ||| undefined` yourself in ghci to see!

Comment: @DanielWagner: now, try `False ||| undefined`. The result of `False ||| anything` is uniquely determined by `anything`, and thus, as long as you don't look at `anything`, this should work. Only when you actually look at `anything` (i.e. `undefined` in this case), should it blow up. I agree that "short-circuiting" is not the best term to describe this behavior. I should have left it at "non-strict in its right argument".

Comment: @JörgWMittag Your definition of `|||` also blows up when you try `False ||| undefined`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag As you can see [in this ideone](http://ideone.com/huSPUC), FredOverflow's implementation has exactly the same denotation as yours.

Comment: have a +1 for `Buul`

Answer (score 3):

Another way to express the logical operators as an integer arithmetic expressions (where feasible). This way can avoid lots of branching for a larger expression of many predicates..

Let True be 1
Let False be 0

if the summation of both is greater than 1 then it is true or false to be returned.

```
boolean isOR(boolean arg1, boolean arg2){

   int L = arg1 ? 1 : 0;
   int R = arg2 ? 1 : 0;

   return (L+R) > 0;

}
```

Comment: `booleanExpression ? true : false` is trivially equal to `booleanExpression`.

Comment: I like your methodology but a simple mistake is that the sum of both arguments must be greater than ZERO to be true, not greater than ONE.

Comment: `return (arga+argb)>0`

Comment: I just thought you might want to revise this point you wrote: "if the summation of both is greater than 1 then it is true or false to be returned" to zero instead of 1...

Comment: I was only correcting your text. Your code is perfect, but could be in one line: `return (((arg1 ? 1 : 0)+(arg2 ? 1 : 0)) > 0);`  :)

Comment: @Cory - I suppose you presumed the programming language to be C like?  1 <> true or 0 <> false in many other languages..for example it is not the case in Java. 

My intention was not to give a syntac corrected, all boundary conditions covered, well compact code..let's spare ourselves of that..it was intended to present a 'technique' rather.

Comment: @Grantly thanks for pointing out the error in the text. Yes it should be "strictly greater than 0"

Comment: @SenthuSivasambu In the case of your code, I made no such presumption. A comparison operation such as `>` returns a Boolean value of `true` or `false`. In general, you can trim down `true ? true : false` or `false ? true : false` because these always evaluate to `true` and `false` respectively.

Comment: @SenthuSivasambu I have no objections to your use of `arg1 ? 1 : 0;`. Those are reliable expressions for transforming a Boolean into a number. It's only the return statement that can be trivially refactored.

Comment: oh..my bad. point taken. Yes. it can be. Rookie mistake... :O

Comment: @Cory I have corrected and have given credit to you for pointing out. However my comment is not appearing to me..

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to define OR, or indeed any logical operator, using the most traditional way of defining it: use a truth table.

This is of course quite trivial to do in higher level languages such as Javascript or Perl but I'm writing this example in C to show that the technique does not depend on high level language features:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    // Define truth table for OR:
    int OR[2][2] = {
        {0,   // false, false
         1},  // false, true
        {1,   // true, false
         1}   // true, true
    }

    // Let's test the definition
    printf("false || false = %d\n",OR[1==2]['b'=='a']);
    printf("true || false = %d\n",OR[10==10]['b'=='a']);

    // Usage:
    if (OR[ 1==2 ][ 3==4 ]) {
        printf("at least one is true\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("both are false\n");
    }
}
```

You can do the same with AND, NOR, NAND, NOT and XOR. The code is clean enough to look like syntax such that you can do stuff like this:

```
if (OR[ a ][ AND[ b ][ c ] ]) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: I think this is the "purest" approach in certain mathematical sense. The OR-operator is a function after all, and the truth table is really the essence of that function as a relation and a set. Of course this could be written in an amusing OO manner too: `BinaryOperator or = new TruthTableBasedBinaryOperator(new TruthTable(false, true, true, true));`

Answer (score 1):

The two forms:

```
OR(arg1, arg2)
  if arg1
     return True
  else:
     return arg2
```

OR

```
OR(arg1, arg2)
  if arg1
     return arg1
  else:
     return arg2
```

Have as well as the code golf-like advantage of being a bit smaller than the other suggestions so far, one less branch. It's not even that silly a micro-opt to reduce the number of branches if we're considering the creation of a primitive that would hence be very heavily used.

Javascript's definition of `||` is akin to this, which combined with its loose typing means that the expression `false || "abc"` has the value `"abc"` and `42 || "abc"` has the value `42`.

Though if you already have other logical operators then the likes of `nand(not(arg1), not(arg2))` might have the advantage of no branching at all.

Comment: what's the point of repeating the prior answer ([as you admitted](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/266592/how-to-define-or-logically/266635#comment542424_266600))?

Comment: @gnat it's close enough that I wouldn't have bothered had I seen that answer, but it does still have something to it not found in any of them, so I'm leaving it.

Comment: @gnat, actually considering "We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context." I'm happier with this answer now.

Answer (score 1):

All the good answers have already been given. But I won't let that stop me.

```
// This will break when the arguments are additive inverses.
// It is "cleverness" like this that's behind all the most amazing program errors.
or(arg1, arg2)
    return arg1 + arg2
    // Or if you need explicit conversions:
    // return (bool)((short)arg1 + (short)arg2)
```

Alternatively:

```
// Since `0 > -1`, negative numbers will cause weirdness.
or(arg1, arg2)
    return max(arg1, arg2)
```

I hope no one would ever actually use approaches like these. They're here only to promote awareness of alternatives.

**Update:**

Since negative numbers can break both of the above approaches, here is another awful suggestion:

```
or(arg1, arg2)
    return !(!arg1 * !arg2)
```

This simply uses [DeMorgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and abuses the fact that `*` is similar to `&&` when `true` and `false` are treated like `1` and `0` respectively. (Wait, you're saying this *isn't* code golf?)

Here's a decent answer:

```
or(arg1, arg2)
    return arg1 ? arg1 : arg2
```

But that's essentially identical to other answers already given.

Comment: These approaches are fundamentally flawed. Consider -1+1 for `arg1+arg2`, -1 and 0 for `max(arg1,arg2)`, etc.

Comment: @fluffy This approach assumes Boolean arguments, and then it just happens to work correctly with most kinds of garbage input. Good of you to point out that there's still some garbage which produces issues. This kind of thing is exactly why we should seek to model the actual problem domain as directly as possible (and avoid getting carried away by our own cleverness) in practice.

Comment: If you're doing pure 1-bit boolean values, then addition still doesn't work, since 1+1 = 0. :)

Comment: @fluffy That's where the explicit conversions come in. Whether or not they're needed depends on the details of the implementation (which is exactly why this is a silly idea).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all the programmed solutions using the if construct, it's possible to construct an OR gate by combining three NAND gates.  If you want to see how it's done in wikipedia, [click here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic#OR).

From this, the expression,

> NOT[ NOT( A AND A ) AND NOT( B AND B )]

which uses NOT and AND gives the same answer as OR.  Notice that the use of both NOT and AND is just an obscure way of expressing NAND.

Comment: NOT(A AND A) == NOT(A) ?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  In the same wikipedia article, you can see how they reduce a NOT gate to NAND gates.  Same for an AND gate.  I chose not to edit the formula they presented for the OR gate.

Answer (score 0):

One way to define `or` is via a lookup table.  We can make this explicit:

```
bool Or( bool a, bool b } {
  bool retval[] = {b,true}; // or {b,a};
  return retval[a];
}
```

we create an array with the values that the return value should have depending on what `a` is.  Then we do a lookup.  In C++ like languages, `bool` promotes to a value that can be used as an array index, with `true` being `1` and `false` being `0`.

We can then extend this to other logical operations:

```
bool And( bool a, bool b } {
  bool retval[] = {false,b}; // or {a,b};
  return retval[a];
}
bool Xor( bool a, bool b } {
  bool retval[] = {b,!b};
  return retval[a];
}
```

Now a downside of all of these is that it requires prefix notation.

```
namespace operators {
  namespace details {
    template<class T> struct is_operator {};
    template<class Lhs, Op> struct half_expression { Lhs&& lhs; };
    template<class Lhs, class Op>
    half_expression< Lhs, Op > operator*( Lhs&&lhs, is_operator<Op> ) {
      return {std::forward<Lhs>(lhs)};
    }
    template<class Lhs, class Op, class Rhs>
    auto operator*( half_expression<Lhs, Op>&& lhs, Rhs&& rhs ) {
    return invoke( std::forward<Lhs>(lhs.lhs), Op{}, std::forward<Rhs>(rhs) );
    }
  }
  using details::is_operator;
}

struct or_tag {};
static const operators::is_operator<or_tag> OR;

bool invoke( bool a, or_tag, bool b ) {
  bool retval[] = {b,true};
  return retval[a];
}
```

and now you can type `true *OR* false` and it works.

The above technique requires a language that supports argument dependent lookup, and templates.  You could probably do it in a language with generics and ADL.

As an aside, you can extend the `*OR*` above to work with sets.  Simply create a free function `invoke` in the same namespace as `or_tag`:

```
template<class...Ts>
std::set<Ts...> invoke( std::set<Ts...> lhs, or_tag, std::set<Ts...> const& rhs ) {
  lhs.insert( rhs.begin(), rhs.end() );
  return lhs;
}
```

and now `set *OR* set` returns the union of the two.

Answer (score 0):

This one remembers me the charasteristic functions:

```
or(a, b)
    return a + b - a*b
```

This only applies to languages which can treat booleans as (1, 0). Does not apply to Smalltalk or Python since boolean is a class. In smalltalk they go even further (this will be written in sort of a pseudocode):

```
False::or(a)
    return a

True::or(a)
    return self
```

And the dual methods exist for and:

```
False::and(a)
    return self

True::and(a)
    return a
```

So the "logic" is perfectly valid in the OP statement, althought it is verbose. Beware, it is not bad. It is perfect if you need a function which acts like a mathematical operator based on, say, a kind of matrix. Others would implement an actual cube (like a Quine-McCluskey statement):

```
or = array[2][2] {
    {0, 1},
    {1, 1}
}
```

And you will evaluate or[a][b]

So yes, every logic here is valid (except that one posted as using the in-language OR operator xDDDDDDDD).

But my favorite one is the DeMorgan's law: `!(!a && !b)`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Swift standard library and check out their implementation of the shortcut OR and shortcut AND operations, which *don’t* evaluate the second operands if not needed/allowed.

Answer (score -2):

The logic is perfectly correct, but can be simplified:

```
or(arg1, arg2)
  if arg1 = True
     return True
  else if arg2 = True
     return True
  else
     return False
```

And presumably your language has an OR operator so - unless it's against the spirit of the question - why not

```
or(arg1, arg2)
  if arg1 = True or arg2 = True
     return True
  else
     return False
```

Comment: `if arg1 = True or arg2 = True { return true } else { return false }` Better yet, `return arg1 = True or arg2 = True`. `if condition then true else false` is redundant.

Comment: asker specifically pointed that their requirement was "without using the operator itself"

Comment: Um, I didn't say anything of the sort.  It was kind of what I meant, but the question didn't say so until it was edited, and she answered it as such, so kind of my fault on that one.